# Conventional function for beta decay spectrum?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

Is there a conventional functional form for a beta decay spectrum, specifically where something like "Counts" is on the y-axis, and energy is on the x-axis?

For things like gammas, the Gaussian function is typically used for modeling, but for betas, there's usually an end-point energy, like shown below.  I want to know if there is a commonly used mathematical model for this, and what that is.

Of course, I can make my own function up using Heaviside thetas, or some confluence of exponentials, but I want to know if there is a widely used or highly regarded function (like the Gaussian for gammas).

[image]